# php replace file extension by association

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've setup a preg_replace to add a .gz file extension to image filenames. But I need to change the file extension associatively (so that bmp -> bmp.gz, png -> png.gz, etc.). What can I put in place of the $old_extension variable to do this?

```
$new_file_ext = 
preg_replace('"\.(bmp|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$"', '.' . $old_extension . '.gz', $filename );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  back-refrence the chars present inside the group index 1. Capturing groups have the nature of capturing al the characters which are matched by the pattern present inside those groups. So here the pattern present inside the capturing group is `bmp|gif|png|jpg|jpeg`. In the replacement part, we could refer those chars which are present in a group by specifying it's index number like `\1` (which refers to the first capturing group).

```
preg_replace('~\.(bmp|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$~', '.\1.gz', $filename );
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iA0dZ2/1)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. Also appreciate the demo on regex101.com. Hadn't seen that before.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply append the extension to it?

```
$new = $old.".gz";
```

Answer (score 0):

Better approach is [strtr](http://php.net/strtr) function, it takes an assoc array, like this:

```
<?php    
$trans = array("bpm" => "bpm.gz","jpg" => "jpg.gz");
echo strtr($filename, $trans);
?>
```

---

edit:
to be sure extension is replaced, do the usual

1. `$ext = explode('.',$filename)` [explode](http://php.net/explode)
2. `$ext[key(end($ext))] = strtr($ext[key(end($ext))], $trans);` translate just extension
3. implode back `return join('',$ext)`;